DHCP doesn't work with NetworkManager, but does with other tools
I have a server with 2 ethernet devices eth0 and eth2, managed by NetworkManager. There is no configuration in /etc/NetworkManager and both connections have ipv4.method to auto. The connection at eth0 is working, but eth2 doesn't get an IP and NetworkManager loops trying to reactivate and request an IP again and again:
Nov 25 18:00:39 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554039.7010] policy: auto-activating connection 'eth2' (uuid)
Nov 25 18:00:39 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554039.7018] device (eth2): Activation: starting connection 'eth2' (uuid)
Nov 25 18:00:39 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554039.7019] device (eth2): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', managed-type: 'full')
Nov 25 18:00:39 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554039.7024] device (eth2): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', managed-type: 'full')
Nov 25 18:00:39 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554039.7035] device (eth2): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', managed-type: 'full')
Nov 25 18:00:39 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554039.7049] dhcp4 (eth2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554084.6625] device (eth2): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', managed-type: 'full')
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <warn>  [1732554084.6632] device (eth2): Activation: failed for connection 'eth2'
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554084.6635] device (eth2): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', managed-type: 'full')
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554084.6881] dhcp4 (eth2): canceled DHCP transaction
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554084.6882] dhcp4 (eth2): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554084.6882] dhcp4 (eth2): state changed no lease
Nov 25 18:01:24 host NetworkManager[72358]: <info>  [1732554084.6910] policy: auto-activating connection 'eth2' (uuid)
...

This led me to think that there was an issue with DHCP, but that's not the case. DHCP works fine at the network/hardware level, I checked with different tools including dhcpcd and nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover and get an IP. Also, if I let NetworkManager do its thing, tcpdump tells it gets a reply, but seems to ignore it:
tcpdump -i eth2 -n port 67 and port 68
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
18:11:18.660972 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from <mac>, length 283
18:11:18.667161 IP 10.91.179.129.67 > 10.91.179.152.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
18:11:18.667256 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from <mac>, length 295
18:11:21.527720 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from <mac>, length 295
18:11:26.157492 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from <mac>, length 295
18:11:34.865526 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from <mac>, length 295

I can work around that by using another network daemon, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with NetworkManager.

Do you get any more details after using nmcli gen log level debug?

The only relevant thing I see is (eth2): ip:dhcp4: set state none (was pending). Just before dhcp4 (eth2): canceled DHCP transaction. But nothing in the log indicate why it decided to cancel the transaction :/

I assume it's multi-homed, so perhaps packets are being sent out on the other interface due to being on the same subnet?
